# Safely turn of BucketVersioning in S3 using Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am new to S3 , I have a unit test where I turn on the versioning do a few operations and then suspend the versioning. But I want to always Suspend the versioning even if the test case fails.
Here is my implementation :-

```
            @Test
            public void checkVersion() {
            AWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials("","");
            AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(creds);
            BucketVersioningConfiguration configuration = 
                            new BucketVersioningConfiguration().withStatus("Enabled");


    SetBucketVersioningConfigurationRequest setBucketVersioningConfigurationRequest = new SetBucketVersioningConfigurationRequest(bucketName,configuration);
     s3Client.setBucketVersioningConfiguration(setBucketVersioningConfigurationRequest);

//PUt object
//Delete object
//Put object


        }
```

Now I want to turn off the bucketversioning everytime even if the operations fail. For this is there any other better way other than using

```
try-catch-finally block
```

Also , is it possible to implement Enable and Suspend versions using `try-with-resource` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a finally block is fine to do the cleanup.

You cannot use try-with-resource, because it only works with resources that implement `AutoCloseable` - there is nothing like that in the S3 SDK to change the versioning status in a `close()` method.

Another alternative is to use an appropriate "after" method of whatever testing framework you are using (e.g., @AfterClass or @AfterSuite) to do the final cleanup.

However, you should remember that there is no guarantee that your cleanup code will be able to successfully execute (e.g., your machine may crash in the middle of your tests). In these exceptional situations, you might have to manually do all the cleanup/re-setting. Or you can write your tests to not depend on the initial state of the environment.

Comment: Can you know if we can cleanup using try-with-resource ?

Comment: @Newbie I added a note on this in the answer.